# UDP UDP Packets sending with fragmented

Tags: vb.net, udp

We are developing one project where we are sending UDP Packets, we are successfully able to send it. But we further want to fragment our packet if they exceed some limit. The listener with whom we have to communicate is expecting any packet of 1024 and it happens that depending on the content packet may get bigger then expected, so when it goes it should be fragmented and in the wireshark it should show as 2 messages fragments and should be reassembled at the end. I am developing in **vb.net**.

Comment: And you are asking for what? Code to do this? Have you got some that didn't work? Or it's not showing in wireshark? Or?

Comment: Theres no need to "fragment" anything since the network layer already cuts packets into pieces, this behaviour can be adjusted via the `MTU` flag of your network card and IP-stack. If you want to fragment on the APPLICATION layer, on the other hand you simply need to stop filling your data buffer at your pre-set limit and start a new send-operation with the remaining data - note that the actual IP packet always is larger than your data ... but it doesnt matter on the application layer

Comment: also : if you actually need to limit your MTU in order to transfer data between highly restrictive, low-bandwidth / low-latency networks you're most certainly doing something wrong - there are fully suited protocols for these purposes, some of which automatically fragment .... UDP is not actually up to the task if you want to transfer over these networks, in fact UDP may just be the worst possible protocol choice. TCP, for instance is reliable and capable (!) in most networks